# Capturing columns with similar patterns with Python regex

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping a pdf using regex and Python. The patterns repeat through each column. I don't understand how to target each column of information separately.

Text string:

```
2000 2001 2002 2003\n
14,756 10,922 9,745 12,861\n
9,882 11,568 8,176 10,483\n
13,925 10,724 10,032 8,927\n
```

I need to return the data by year like:

```
[('2000', '14,756', '9,882', '13,925'),
('2001', '10,922', '11,568', '10,742'),
('2002', '9,745', '8,176', '10,032'),
('2003', '12,861', '10,483', '8,927')]
```

once I have the regex, I understand how to pull it from the page and put it into a df. I'm just not understanding how to target the columns separately. I just capture everything all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is impossible to capture columns, but you can combine regex with matching the groups of the columns and transpose with `zip`.

```
(?:^|\n)([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)(?:$|\n)
```

See how this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tOqfAM/1) works.

```py
import re

text = """2000 2001 2002 2003
14,756 10,922 9,745 12,861
9,882 11,568 8,176 10,483
13,925 10,724 10,032 8,927"""

pattern = r"(?:^|\n)([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)\s([\d,]+)(?:$|\n)"
grouped = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.M)
columns = list(zip(*grouped))  # the expected result
```